# Proving that a factorial decreases?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I prove, without any use of reduction formula for factorials, that $$\frac{(2n)}{(n!)^2}$$

is decreasing?

Comment: What is a reduction formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{2n}{(n!)^2}$. Observe that\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=\frac{2(n+1)}{((n+1)!)^2}\frac{(n!)^2}{2n} \\
&=\frac{n+1}n \left(\frac{n!}{(n+1)!} \right)^2 \\
&=\frac{n+1}n \left(\frac{1}{n+1} \right)^2  \\
&=\frac 1{n(n+1)} \\
&<1
\end{align}
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $$a_{n+1}<a_n,$$ which establishes that the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply observe that

$$\frac{2n}{(n!)^2}=\frac{2n}{n(n-1)!n!}=\frac2{(n-1)!n!}$$

for $n>0$, so it’s a fraction with a constant numerator and an increasing denominator? (You need to specify that $n>0$ anyway, since the increases from $n=0$ to $n=1$.)

Comment: Ah, the vandals are out again, downvoting everything on the page.